# Issue with multiple quotes in string

Tags: c#, string

I have the following string in c# code.

```
 string home = "<img src='/images/Home.png' 
                     onclick='javascript:document.location.href=/Home/Index' />";
```

When i send this string to client side then click event on image is not working, giving the following error in the console :

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid flags supplied to RegExp constructor 'Index' 
page_home (1):1 onclick
```

I have a feeling that there is something wrong with quotes in the string but i didn't get. What i am doing wrong here ?

Comment: You should use an `<a>`.

Comment: Have you tried quoting the embedded quotes (eg: with \ ?)

Comment: So is this ASP, or what?  If this is indeed ASP you probably shouldn't be sending the HTML as a literal string in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is you haven't encapsulated the location in quotes in the javascript so it's processing it as a regular expression.

This should solve your issue.

```
string home = "<img src=\"/images/Home.png\" onclick=\"javascript:document.location.href='/Home/Index'\" />";
```

You can also do this:

```
string home = @"<img src=""/images/Home.png"" onclick=""javascript:document.location.href='/Home/Index'"" />";
```

Comment: Just to stress: it is the string on the right side of `document.location.href` assignment that was not quoted. And it probably still needs `/` at the start.